# How do you set the border width style of listview items?

Tags: listview

How can you set the border of list view items thanks.

Comment: and style these. Need to be able to set individually.  whats best way

Comment: What platform? WPF/WinForms/Android...

Comment: Judging from the fact that your user name is "Androider", do you want to do this on an *Android*? If so, please tag your questions accordingly. There are lots of GUI frameworks that have a `ListView` control.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your border in the ControlTemplate, something like below:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderedListView" TargetType="ListViewItem">   
   <Setter Property="Template">  
    <Setter.Value> <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
           BorderThickness="3"> 
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate> </Setter.Value>   
   </Setter>  
</Style>
```

After you set the border in the ControlTemplate, you can set the following style in ListView :

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BorderedListView}" />
```

Comment: And I assume this is for android platform, as your user name is "Androider".